# Find object by text in selenium ide

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

need help
need to find tst_user span in selenium ide and click it

```
<div class="v-filterselect-suggestmenu" style="width: 149px;">
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="gwt-MenuItem" role="listitem">
<span>tst_user</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
//span[text()='tst_user']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

//*[contains(text(),'tst_user')]

Or :

css=tag:contains(“inner text”)

Regards,
Tarun